# How to find the roots of $(w−1)^4 +(w−1)^3 +(w−1)^2 +w=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Write down, in any form, all the roots of the equation $z^5 − 1 = 0$
>
> Hence find all the roots of the equation
>
> $$(w−1)^4 +(w−1)^3 +(w−1)^2 +w=0$$
>
> and deduce that none of them is real

My Try:

I know how to do the first part:

$$z^5=1=cos 2\pi k + i sin 2\pi k$$

$$z= cos \frac{2\pi k}{5}+ i sin \frac{2\pi k}{5}$$

where $k=0,1,2,3,4$

---

Please help me to do the second part. Thanks.

Attempt:

$$z^5-1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+1)=0$$

Have to find:

$$(w−1)^4 +(w−1)^3 +(w−1)^2 +w=0$$

Let $w=z+1$

$$z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$$

Multiply by $(z-1)$ each side:

$$(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)=0 (z-1)=0$$

$$z^5-1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)=0$$

$$z^5-1=0$$ (back to Inital result)

Then

$$z=cos \frac{2\pi k}{5}+ i sin \frac{2\pi k}{5}$$

Since $w=z+1$ So $z=w-1$

$$w-1=cos \frac{2\pi k}{5}+ i sin \frac{2\pi k}{5}$$

$$w=cos \frac{2\pi k}{5}+ i sin \frac{2\pi k}{5}+1$$

This seems weird, is this correct?

Comment: Can you put $z= ?$ to simplify the second equation?

Comment: Recall that $z^5-1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)$, for all $z\in \mathbb C$.

Comment: @MarkBennet $z=w-1$? (It's a wild guess)

Comment: Use "$z^5-1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+1)$" to proceed.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Ok thank you :) Wait let me try .

Comment: If you multiply out (polynomial long multiplication) you will find that your final product comes out to $z^5-1$. If you have $p(z)=0$ then $q(z)p(z)=0$ will also be true - but going that way doesn't help much. Here it is convenient to find the roots of $q(z)p(z)=0$, some of which will be roots of $p$ - you will have to eliminate the root belonging to the factor $z-1$ you have introduced.

Comment: @columbus8myhw , used it , is it correct (edited my question)? UMMM looks weird. So it's just +1 that came in extra after all?

Comment: @MarkBennet didn't quite get that. I continued my working (edited the question). Take a look? :)

Comment: First off: when you multiplied by $z-1$, you added in an extra solution to the equation. (That is, $z^4+\dotsb+1=0$ has four roots, while $z^5-1=0$ has five—the original four, plus $z=1$). Secondly, that _is_ correct (except $w$ isn't $2$). You can see that your answer implies that $w=\xi+1$ where $\xi$ is any (not $1$) fifth root of unity.

Comment: @columbus8myhw How do I do it then? :/

Comment: @TheArtist ...I just said that you were right. (Except that $z=1\iff w=2$ isn't a solution, but that's just because you multiplied both sides by $z-1$ at some point.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw I mean, if I didn't multiply how else can I get the result? I see no way of proceeding without multiplication.

Comment: @TheArtist You _do_ need to multiply. Just remember that if $f(x)=0$ has roots, then $(x-1)f(x)=0$ has the same roots (plus $x=1$ if that wasn't a root of $f$ already). But, in your problem, multiplying is the only way to proceed. (And it's easy to check that $1$ isn't a root of $z^4+\dotsb+1$, so we don't have to worry about that.)

Comment: Thank you very much @columbus8myhw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks good: $z^5-1=0$ has five solutions that are evenly distributed around the unit circle, as defined by your trigonometric solution.  These are the black points in the following figure:

[image]

As you say, the left hand side factors into
$$z^5-1 = (z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1).$$

If we divide off the first order term and substitute $z=w-1$ into the remaining we get
$$z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1 = (w-1)^4 + (w-1)^3 + (w-1)^2 + (w-1) + 1.$$
Thus, the roots of the polynomial in $w$ are exactly the (non-real) roots of the polynomial shifted to the right, as shown in red.  Hence, they cannot be real.

Comment: (+1) Thank you mark a lot. One question: what do you mean as "first order" ? And how can you simply divide off? Can you add these steps to your answer, appreciate it a lot. This is a very nice answer.

Comment: @TheArtist The $z-1$ term is a *first order* polynomial. We divide it off to focus on the roots of the other part.  Of course, we still need to account for the roots of both parts at the end.

Comment: Can you show me how you divided ? :) Like mathematically, how did you divide it off ? :) Can you  add the step where you divided in your answer? Thanks again :)

Comment: @TheArtist Here's a better way to put it: If $H(x)=f(x)g(x)=0$, then we can find the roots of $H$ by separately considering the roots of $f$ and $g$. If we're trying to solve $(x-1)(x^2-4)$, for example, we see that $x= \pm 2$ are solutions arsing from the second term. Of course, $x=1$ is also a solution from the first part, but this doesn't complicate our analysis of the second.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes :D Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

$$y:=w-1 \iff y^4+y^3+y^2+y+1=0 \stackrel{\cdot (y-1)}{\iff} (y-1)(y^4+y^3+y^2+y+1)=0 \iff y^5-1=0  \;\forall y\neq 1$$

Comment: I don't understand :/ Did you skip steps?

Comment: @TheArtist if I define $y:=w-1$ then your equality becomes the one I posted with $y$s. Then I multiply by $y-1$ to get a known identity. I also assumed $y\neq 1$ to do that multiplication.

Comment: Thank you. Can you check my working at the end? I have used what you said , but still Im stuck. I edited my question, take a look please :)